# kick off - usage

Tags: word-usage, usage, idiomatic-language, slang

If someone does something suddenly, is it correct to say that he did it "from a kick-off"?

Another situation: if someone gets angry, is it correct to answer "don't kick off"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different idioms.

1. The verb *kick off* means literally "start" (certain games, in particular soccer), and in transferred usage "start a process or activity". It has an associated noun "kick-off" which is also used figuratively, though in my experience less often than the verb.

But it doesn't have the meaning "suddenly"; It is rather "from the beginning". So

> He did it from the kick-off.

means that he started doing it right at the start of the project or activity. (note "the", not "a")

2. The verb *kick off* also has a colloquial meaning "make a fuss, argue, protest". So "Don't kick off" is possible in that sense.

See ["kick off" in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_off)